# Is it possible to alias columns programmatically in spark sql?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In spark SQL (perhaps only HiveQL) one can do:

```
select sex, avg(age) as avg_age
from humans
group by sex
```

which would result in a `DataFrame` with columns named `"sex"` and `"avg_age"`.

How can `avg(age)` be aliased to `"avg_age"` without using textual SQL?

**Edit:**
After zero323 's answer, I need to add the constraint that:

*The column-to-be-renamed's name may not be known/guaranteed or even addressable*. In textual SQL, using "select EXPR as NAME" removes the requirement to have an intermediate name for EXPR. This is also the case in the example above, where "avg(age)" could get a variety of auto-generated names (which also vary among spark releases and sql-context backends).

Comment: you can add a alias for your df.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out [`def toDF(colNames: String*): DataFrame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) does exactly that. Pasting from 2.11.7 documentation:

```
def toDF(colNames: String*): DataFrame

Returns a new DataFrame with columns renamed. This can be quite
convenient in conversion from a RDD of tuples into a DataFrame
with meaningful names. For example:

    val rdd: RDD[(Int, String)] = ...
    rdd.toDF()  // this implicit conversion creates a DataFrame
                // with column name _1 and _2
    rdd.toDF("id", "name")  // this creates a DataFrame with
                            // column name "id" and "name"
```

Answer (score 37):

Let's suppose `human_df` is the DataFrame for humans. Since Spark 1.3:

```
human_df.groupBy("sex").agg(avg("age").alias("avg_age"))
```

Comment: Is this Scala? It looks like Python.

Comment: @summerbulb Yes, it is in Python

Answer (score 22):

If you prefer to rename a single column it is possible to use `withColumnRenamed` method:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    Person("Alice", 2) :: Person("Bob", 5) :: Nil) 
df.withColumnRenamed("name", "first_name")
```

Alternatively you can use `alias` method:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.avg

df.select(avg($"age").alias("average_age"))
```

You can take it further with small helper:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def normalizeName(c: Column) = {
  val pattern = "\\W+".r
  c.alias(pattern.replaceAllIn(c.toString, "_"))
}

df.select(normalizeName(avg($"age")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous columns, such as the one that would be generated by `avg(age)` without `AS avg_age`, get automatically assigned names. As you point out in your question, the names are implementation-specific, generated by a naming strategy. If needed, you could write code that sniffs the environment and instantiates an appropriate discovery & renaming strategy based on the specific naming strategy. There are not many of them.

In Spark 1.4.1 with `HiveContext`, the format is "_c*N*" where *N* is the position of the anonymous column in the table. In your case, the name would be `_c1`.