# Aggregate a Spark data frame using an array of column names, retaining the names

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions

I would like to aggregate a Spark data frame using an array of column names as input, and at the same time retain the original names of the columns.

```
df.groupBy($"id").sum(colNames:_*)
```

This works but fails to preserve the names. Inspired by the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538624/is-it-possible-to-alias-columns-programmatically-in-spark-sql) I unsucessfully tried this:

```
df.groupBy($"id").agg(sum(colNames:_*).alias(colNames:_*))
error: no `: _*' annotation allowed here
```

It works to take a single element like

```
df.groupBy($"id").agg(sum(colNames(2)).alias(colNames(2)))
```

How can make this happen for the entire array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just provide an sequence of columns with aliases:

```
val colNames: Seq[String] = ???
val exprs = colNames.map(c => sum(c).alias(c))
df.groupBy($"id").agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*)
```

Comment: Yes, I guessed it would be something like this. However, still can't get it to work. error: no `: _*' annotation allowed here
(such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)

Comment: Sorry, it should be agg not sum.

Comment: Yeah, and I also figured out that colNames should infact be exprs, right?