# Read spark data with column that clashes with partition name

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following file paths that we read with partitions on s3

```
prefix/company=abcd/service=xyz/date=2021-01-01/file_01.json
prefix/company=abcd/service=xyz/date=2021-01-01/file_02.json
prefix/company=abcd/service=xyz/date=2021-01-01/file_03.json
```

When I read these with pyspark

```
self.spark \
    .read \
    .option("basePath", 'prefix') \
    .schema(self.schema) \
    .json(['company=abcd/service=xyz/date=2021-01-01/'])
```

All the files have the same schema and get loaded in the table as rows. A file could be something like this:

```
{"id": "foo", "color": "blue", "date": "2021-12-12"}
```

The issue is that sometimes the files have the date field that clashes with my partition code, like `date`. So I want to know if it is possible to load the files without the partition columns, rename the JSON date column and then add the partition columns.

Final table would be:

```
| id  | color | file_date  | company | service | date       |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| foo | blue  | 2021-12-12 | abcd    | xyz     | 2021-01-01 |
| bar | red   | 2021-10-10 | abcd    | xyz     | 2021-01-01 |
| baz | green | 2021-08-08 | abcd    | xyz     | 2021-01-01 |
```

EDIT:

**More information:** I have 5 or 6 partitions sometimes and date is one of them (not the last). And I need to read multiple date partitions at once too. The schema that I pass to Spark contains also the partition columns which makes it more complicated.

I don't control the input data so I need to read as is. I can rename the file columns but not the partition columns.

Would it be possible to add an alias to file columns as we would do when joining 2 dataframes?

Spark 3.1

Comment: Do you have the possibility to change the schema you pass when loading into df?

Comment: @blackbishop Yes, I define the input schema which now is something like `StructType([*partitions_colums, *file_columns])` but I had to remove the repeated columns from file_columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to list the files under `prefix` S3 path using for example [Hadoop FS API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html), then pass that list to `spark.read`. This way Spark won't detect them as partitions and you'll be able to rename the file columns if needed.

After you load the files into a dataframe, loop through the df columns and rename those which are also present in your `partitions_colums` list (by adding `file` prefix for example).

Finally, parse the partitions from the `input_file_name()` using `regexp_extract` function.

Here's an example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()

s3_path = "s3://bucket/prefix"
file_cols = ["id", "color", "date"]
partitions_cols = ["company", "service", "date"]

# listing all files for input path
json_files = []
files = Path(s3_path).getFileSystem(conf).listFiles(Path(s3_path), True)

while files.hasNext():
    path = files.next().getPath()
    if path.getName().endswith(".json"):
        json_files.append(path.toString())

df = spark.read.json(json_files) # you can pass here the schema of the files without the partition columns

# renaming file column in if exists in partitions
df = df.select(*[
    F.col(c).alias(c) if c not in partitions_cols else F.col(c).alias(f"file_{c}")
    for c in df.columns
])

# parse partitions from filenames
for p in partitions_cols:
    df = df.withColumn(p, F.regexp_extract(F.input_file_name(), f"/{p}=([^/]+)/", 1))

df.show()

#+-----+----------+---+-------+-------+----------+
#|color| file_date| id|company|service|      date|
#+-----+----------+---+-------+-------+----------+
#|green|2021-08-08|baz|   abcd|    xyz|2021-01-01|
#| blue|2021-12-12|foo|   abcd|    xyz|2021-01-01|
#|  red|2021-10-10|bar|   abcd|    xyz|2021-01-01|
#+-----+----------+---+-------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: This is still more complex than I wanted. But seems good enough. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be to simply change the partition column name. You can then read in the data and rename the columns as you wish. You'll not lose the benefits of partitioning either.

If that is not an option you could read in the jsons using a wildcard for the partitions, rename the date column to 'file_date' and then add the partition date by extracting it from the filename. You can get the filename from `input_file_name` in `pyspark.sql.functions`.

Edit: I missed you have other partitioned columns before the date, you'd have to extract them from the filename as well making it less ideal.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I have 5 or 6 partitions sometimes and date is one of them (not the last). And I need to read multiple date partitions at once too.

The schema that I pass to Spark contains also the partition columns which makes it more complicated.

Comment: I added more context to the question

Comment: Ideally you want to be able to differentiate between the partition schema columns and data schema columns but afaik this is currently not possible. Spark does provide a warning, but doesn't offer a solution: `WARN DataSource: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema and the partition schema: 'date'`. If you do find a solution do let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can read all the json files without partition columns.
Directly use the parent folder path and it will load all partitions data into the data frame.

After reading the data frame, you can use withColumn() function to rename the date field.

Something like the following should work

```
df= spark.read.json("s3://bucket/table/**/*.json")

renamedDF= df.withColumnRenamed("old column name","new column name")
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see how I can retrieve the partition columns this way. See my updated question.

Comment: You can add alias to columns if you are using spark sql , something like this - .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538624/is-it-possible-to-alias-columns-programmatically-in-spark-sql.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, your chance is to read json files.

So instead of loading the files without the partition columns, rename the JSON date column and then add the partition columns, you can load the partitions columns without file columns, rename partition columns and then apply schema on file data.

You would have to do the following steps:

- Read your json files as text using `sparkSession.read.text()`
- Change name of partitioned columns using `withColumnRenamed()`
- Convert read json strings to json using `from_json` method
- rename columns as you wish using `withColumnRenamed()`

The complete code would be as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DateType

# schema of json files
schema = StructType([
    StructField('id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('color', StringType(), True),
    StructField('date', DateType(), True)
])

df = sparkSession.read.text('resources') \
    .withColumnRenamed('date', 'partition_date') \
    .withColumn('json', F.from_json(F.col('value'), schema)) \
    .select('company', 'service', 'partition_date', 'json.*') \
    .withColumnRenamed('date', 'file_date') \
    .withColumnRenamed('partition_date', 'date')
```

#### Example

With the following input files `file_01.json` and `file_02.json` under directory `prefix/company=abcd/service=xyz/date=2021-01-01`

##### file_01.json

```json
{"id": "foo", "color": "blue", "date": "2021-12-12"}
{"id": "bar", "color": "red", "date": "2021-12-13"}
{"id": "kix", "color": "yellow", "date": "2021-12-14"}
```

##### file_02.json

```json
{"id": "kaz", "color": "blue", "date": "2021-12-15"}
{"id": "dir", "color": "red", "date": "2021-12-16"}
{"id": "tux", "color": "yellow", "date": "2021-12-17"}
```

You get the following output `df` dataframe:

```
+-------+-------+----------+---+------+----------+
|company|service|      date| id| color| file_date|
+-------+-------+----------+---+------+----------+
|   abcd|    xyz|2021-01-01|kaz|  blue|2021-12-15|
|   abcd|    xyz|2021-01-01|dir|   red|2021-12-16|
|   abcd|    xyz|2021-01-01|tux|yellow|2021-12-17|
|   abcd|    xyz|2021-01-01|foo|  blue|2021-12-12|
|   abcd|    xyz|2021-01-01|bar|   red|2021-12-13|
|   abcd|    xyz|2021-01-01|kix|yellow|2021-12-14|
+-------+-------+----------+---+------+----------+
```